# Calculate the number of fixed-length strings that contain a given word exactly once

Tags: python, string, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

For example given the fixed-length N=10 and the word W="radar". Also we know we have 26 characters.

Then we can "easily" calculate the number of strings as:

radar _ _ _ _ _ -> 26^5-26-1 (because radarradar and radaradar_ is not ok)

_ radar _ _ _ _ -> 26^5-26

_ _ radar _ _ _ -> 26^5

_ _ _ radar _ _ -> 26^5

_ _ _ _ radar _ -> 26^5-26

_ _ _ _ _ radar -> 26^5-26-1

Which is 71288150. Is there a better solution to calculate this? Even, if N can be very large.

Comment: It seems like `_ radar _ _ _ _ -> 26^5-1` should be `26^5-26`, and same for the 5th line. More importantly, it's unclear what 'better' is comparing to; do you mean faster than a brute force search?

Comment: @kcsquared I think because the last four there could be `a d a r` which would be invalid. I think all other letter combos are valid there, if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: Is `w` always a palindrome?

Comment: Why are the first and last -26? Shouldn't they be -2?

Comment: @kcsquared you say the OP is double counting, but your result is larger? Can you explain the valid counting method? I'm not sure I'm understanding the puzzle based on what you're saying.

Comment: @ddejohn Double counting of the exclusions; for example, line 1, 'radar _ _ _ _ _' then excludes all 26 possibilities starting with the 9 letters 'radaradar'. But the 5th line must apparently exclude these as well. For a harder example, like `W=rararara`,  the logic gets more complex. I'm not proposing an alternative, just that the sum will have a structure more like the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Precompute the powers in a single loop upto N-size(word) ( same like dp) .. run a single loop ceil(n/2) times calculate your ans... Print (2*ans) if N-size (word) odd else print (2*ans - last cal)

Comment: These are 6 positions where radar can start in the 10 characters, each of which leaves 5 other positions for any characters, out of all those combinations only 2 are invalid which are both "radarradar"(counted twice).  So the number should (26^5)*6-2 = 71,288,254.  You can generalize this using a function  that computes the maximum number of permutations and subtracts the invalid patterns.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273017/number-of-strings-containing-a-specific-substring @kcsquared ... you were correct.

Comment: @adarsh Actually I wasn't; I was mistakenly testing whether the number of non-overlapping occurrences of 'radar' was 1, while OP wanted to count overlapping occurrences. OP's result of 71288150 was actually correct. OP's derivation of that number is missing a lot of details and doesn't easily generalize, but their bottom-line answer appears to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is largely based on the [software engineering stack thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273160/401796) asking a related question, which itself is based on the KMP algorithm.

The idea is to build a deterministic finite automaton (**DFA**) whose transitions are the lowercase letters that can encode the property of matching a pattern zero, one or 2+ times. For example, with pattern = 'radar', we have a pattern length `n` of `5`, and so we'll have `n + n + 1` states in total in our **DFA**. It's helpful to think of these as 3 rows of states:

- Row `0`, column `i` is the state corresponding to `0` full matches, and the last `i` letters seen form our current partial match.
- Row `1`, column `i` is the state corresponding to `1` full match, and the last `i` letters seen form our current partial match.
- Row `2` has a single state which can't be escaped: We have seen at least `2` full matches already.

Our 'row' can only ever increase. In the code, there's really only one flat list of `2n+1` states, but that's just an implementation detail.

A partial drawing of the DFA graph for 'radar' is shown: almost all edges are not drawn, since every state has `26` outward transitions. Usually at most two transitions do not lead back to the 'mismatch' states at the start of a row (here, `0` and `5`), but I also couldn't include some back edges where networkx would draw them overlapping.

[image: DFA for radar]

To get the answer, we need to count the frequencies of being in each possible state (starting from 0) after seeing `length = 10` letters-- the good states are `n, n+1 ... 2n-1`, which correspond to exactly one full match. To generate the transition matrix, we can use the prefix function from the KMP algorithm, with almost no modifications. The definition of the DFA for the first row is as follows:

```c
For state 0 <= i < n,
DFA[i][letter] = Length of longest suffix of (pattern[:i]+letter)
                 that is also a prefix of pattern
```

with the caveat that a full match in state `n-1` moves us to row 1. The definition for states `n <= i < 2n` is the same, just with every state shifted up by `n`.

Using numpy, we can get an answer using matrix powers fairly quickly: we need to raise a roughly `2nx2n` matrix to the power of our fixed `length`. If `length` is too large, you'll either need to use Python's big integers or take moduli to avoid overflow, once the answer gets too large. However, matrix exponentiation can be done with repeated squaring for a time complexity of `O(n^3 * log(length))` using naive matrix multiplication.

```py
def kmp_count(pattern: str, length: int) -> int:
    if not pattern.islower():
        raise ValueError("Pattern must be lowercase")

    n = len(pattern)

    if n > length:
        return 0
    if n == length:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return length * pow(25, length - 1)

    pattern_chars = [ord(x) - ord('a') for x in pattern]

    # Create the DFA
    dfa = [[0 for _ in range(26)] for _ in range(2 * n + 1)]

    # Final failure state is an absorbing state
    dfa[2 * n] = [2 * n for _ in range(26)]

    dfa[0][pattern_chars[0]] = 1
    restart_state = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        dfa[i] = dfa[restart_state][:]

        dfa[i][pattern_chars[i]] = i + 1
        restart_state = dfa[restart_state][pattern_chars[i]]

    dfa[n - 1][pattern_chars[n - 1]] += restart_state

    for i in range(n, 2 * n):
        dfa[i] = [x + n for x in dfa[i - n]]

    # Two or more matches moves us to fail state
    dfa[2 * n - 1][pattern_chars[n - 1]] = 2 * n

    transitions = np.zeros((2 * n + 1, 2 * n + 1), dtype=np.int64)
    for i, x in enumerate(dfa):
        for y in x:
            transitions[i][y] += 1

    final_transitions = np.linalg.matrix_power(transitions, length)
    return final_transitions[0, n:2 * n].sum()
```

```py
print(kmp_count(pattern='radar', length=10))
>>> 71288150
```